# Both WebRTC peers initiate ICE restart simultaneously

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p, sdp

I am fairly new to webRTC. The problem pertains to ICE restart. Let's say there are 2 peers connected using webRTC and one of them loses connection. Now, the peer connection will first go into "disconnected" state. And shortly after, if there is still no connection, goes into "failed" state.

Now, I understand once this failed state is reached, I have to perform an ICE restart. The problem is that even though one peer loses connection, both peers will report "failed" state and try to perform ICE restart, which I believe should be problematic. Here is a snippet of the code:

```
if (peer.localConnection.iceConnectionState == "failed") {
            // create an offer
                peer.localConnection.createOffer({
                    iceRestart : true
                }).then(function(offer) {
                    peer.localConnection.setLocalDescription(offer);
                    // forward the offer to the signaling server
                    var msg = createMsg("OFFER", myId, peerId, offer);
                    sendToSignallingServer(msg);
                }, function(error) {
                    //error
                });
        }
```

I understand that upon finding that there are now two offers, one of the peers should perform a "rollback" using RTCSessionDescription("rollback"). But I am confused whether this will work or not since both the peers might try to perform rollback.

How I can I make sure that only one peer performs a rollback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to avoid the situation (as rollback is not widely implemented yet) is to only do the ice restart when your side of the connection sent the initial offer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Let's say we have peer_A and peer_B. The situation I am facing is: peer_A loses connection. peer_A and peer_B both go into disconnected state. After 15 sec (I am using Chrome) timeout, peer_A and peer_B go into failed state and perform ICE restart and send their offers. This is where I am confused as to how to stop ONLY one peer from sending offer. How can I distinguish between the peers since both run the same code. Note: my problem would be solved if only I could increase this timeout of 15s but unfortunately it looks like it is browser enforced and cannot be changed.

Comment: you typically know if you called createOffer initially and need to store that state yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the help. That seems to be a good solution.
Another thing I am confused about is ICE restart. So, let's say peer A connects for the first time and creates an offer and sends it. In this case the iceRestart parameter should be false. Then let's say connection loss happens and the peer does a ice restart with parameter true. This should work. But if connection loss happens again, it doesn't work anymore since the previous offer also had iceRestart true. This is what I understand from Taylor's cmt:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/discuss-webrtc/gGPKiKQGMHg 

Is it correct?

Comment: even when you do not want to use [trickle-ice](https://webrtchacks.com/trickle-ice/) , calling createOffer() in step 3 is not what you want as you can simply access the local description including candidates as pc.localDescription

Comment: It's true that I can access the local description the way you specified. But I am confused regarding your comment of not calling createOffer(). How can I perform ICE restart without even calling createOffer()?